# Pass Data to UINavigationController Partent

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've got a VC (root) that calls a Modal Segue to a UINavigatioController (settings). The user can change what they want. How do I let the first VC (root) know that the changes are done. the UINav's delegate is the (root) VC. any ideas to pass data back from a modal segue? cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your AppDelegate as a central communication hub that child VCs can call, and pass data to. Try the following:

First set up a shared delegate class method, and a method to pass data to a child VC, in your AppDelegate like so:

```
// In MyAppDelegate.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject {
// rootviewcontroller is the parent of your UINavigationController
UIViewController *rootViewController;
}
+ (MyAppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate;
-(void)passData:(NSString*)myString;
```

and so..

```
// In MyAppDelegate.m

#import "MyAppDelegate.h"

@implementation MyAppDelegate.m

+ (MyAppDelegate.m *)sharedAppDelegate
{
    return (MyAppDelegate.m *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
}

-(void)passData:(NSString*)myString{

// pass data to parent of UINavigationController
[rootViewController hereIsSomeData:myString];

}
```

and then from the .m file of your UINavigationController (VC.m), you import your AppDelegate class and instantiate a shared delegate, which will essentially let you "call" the AppDelegate and send it data..

```
// In VC.m
#import "MyAppDelegate.h";

// ...
NSString *myString = @"alskdjfalsdjfq324r";
[[MyAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] passData:myString];
```

Comment: Awesome solution !!!! thanks a ton ... well said "app delegate as the central communication hub". This would be a cool solution to hold delegates that aren't part of the same navigation controller. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

There's also another way. You can create a mutable object, such as an NSMutableDictionary in the parent controller and pass that to the child controller. Any changes made to the NSMutableDictionary in the child controller carry over to the original parent controller, since they are both pointers to the same object in memory. Good luck!