# Pass data across child navigation controllers

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, segue

**Overview**

I have an iOS project which contains 2 navigation controllers as shown in the pic attached below.

I would like to pass some data when it segues from AAA to CCC but there is a navigation controller between AAA and CCC.

[image]

According to Apple's documentation, UINavigationController shouldn't be subclassed, so I can't create a delegate and pass data.

**Question:**

- how can I pass data from AAA to CCC ?
- any work arounds to achieve this ?

Comment: Why do you have the extra navigation controller between AAA & CCC? Why not just Segue from AAA to CCC directly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a pointer to the navigation controller, you can get its viewControllers array.  In that array, objectAtIndex:0 will be CCC.

Comment: when you segue from AAA to the navigation controller, CCC wouldn't have been created yet. let me know if i am wrong

Comment: I found a nice solution in another post (link given below):

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450545/pass-data-to-uinavigationcontroller-partent

The appDelegate could contain the delegates which could be accessed from anywhere.

Comment: Don't use the app delegate as a source for communicating global state.  CCC will be created at the same time the nav controller is created.

Comment: Here's a good blog post on the topic http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who is unclear on how to implement the accepted answer, here is a code example to more clearly explain how to "[have a pointer to the navigation controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832518/ios-pass-data-across-child-navigation-controller#answer-9832549)." The following code passes an NSString from AAA (AAAViewController) to CCC (CCCViewController) with an identifier named "ToCCC" for the segue.

1) Create a pointer to `foo` in `CCCViewController.h`.

```
//  CCCViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CCCViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *foo;

@end
```

2) In `AAAViewController.m`, create a pointer to CCCViewController (via the navigation controller) and then set `foo`.

```
//  AAAViewController.m

#import "AAAViewController.h"
#import "CCCViewController.h" // Note the import statement for CCC.

@implementation AAAViewController

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"ToCCC"])
    {
        CCCViewController *ccc = [[segue.destinationViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex: 0];
        ccc.foo = @"A string passed from AAA";
    }
}

@end
```

3) Do something with `foo` in `CCCViewController.m` (e.g. log it to the console).

```
//  CCCViewController.m

#import "CCCViewController.h"

@implementation CCCViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Log foo to the console.
    NSLog(@"%@", _foo);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice solution is to create a category on UIStoryboardSeque

UIStoryboardSegue+TopLevel.h

```
@interface UIStoryboardSegue (TopLevel)

@property (readonly) id topLevelDestinationViewController;

@end
```

UIStoryboardSegue+TopLevel.m

```
@implementation UIStoryboardSegue (TopLevel)

- (id)topLevelDestinationViewController
{
    id dest = self.destinationViewController;
    if ([dest isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UINavigationController* nav = dest;
        dest = nav.topViewController;
    }
    return dest;
}

@end
```

Then to use the category

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    [super prepareForSegue:segue sender:sender];

     if ([[segue topLevelDestinationViewController] respondsToSelector:@selector(setSomeProperty:)]) 
     {
        [[segue topLevelDestinationViewController] performSelector:@selector(setSomeProperty:) withObject:self.someProperty];
     }
}
```

That way your code can become very generic, and it doesn't matter if the destination view controller for the segue is a navigation controller or not